Generating Java Classes from a WSDL that only use complex Types
I have the task to implement a SOAP Webservice using a WSDL.
I started using CXF version 3.6.3 and the classes a getting created but i noticed that all the variables are using the type JAXBElement which i've never seen before when using CXF.
After looking into the WSDL i noticed that all the elements of the classes are complex type like this example :
<xs:complexType name="PolizaDTO">
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:extension base="tns:PolizaBaseDTO">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AgenteFinanciero" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <DefaultValue EmitDefaultValue="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AliasRiesgo" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <DefaultValue EmitDefaultValue="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AplicarAExtornos" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>

Because of this the variables are always created with the JAXBElement in the type like this:
public class PolizaDTO
    extends PolizaBaseDTO
{

    @XmlElementRef(name = "AgenteFinanciero", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mpm.seg.ServiceModel.DTO.DataContracts.Polizas", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> agenteFinanciero;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "AliasRiesgo", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mpm.seg.ServiceModel.DTO.DataContracts.Polizas", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> aliasRiesgo;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "AplicarAExtornos", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mpm.seg.ServiceModel.DTO.DataContracts.Polizas", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Short> aplicarAExtornos;

Is there any way to generate the classes without the JAXBElement so i can use it read and create the classes without having to go thougt the pain of dealing with create JAXBElements?
The creator of the WS have said that it was originaly created to be used for C# but we only use Java.
I'm my case i'm able to Read/Convert the data return by the WS in this way but if i have to create a PolizaDTO class i have to inicialize the JAXBElement with the QName and the type and for the number of  variables i have in the class it would be to much work, if anyone knows a way to simplify the process of setting the value in the class or to generate the variables without the JAXBElements it woudl be greatly apreciated.
I have tried to generate the classes with the extraargs to change the -feCliente but using any other way than the default returns an error generating the classes.
I have also tried to generate using XMLBeans and JAXB but the all have the same problem.
Right now i don't know if i'm implementing the WSDL wrong or if i'm using the classes in the wrong way.
